# How to name a dynamically create Persistent Volume?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am using `azure-csi` driver to dynamically create `Persistent Volume` and attach it to my `Pod`. I observed that the `Presistent Volume` which is created has dynamic names like `pvc-12asdaxxxxx`. Is there a way to assign a proper name (or prefix) for the `Persistent Volume`? My storage class config is :

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: azuredisk-premium-retain
provisioner: disk.csi.azure.com
parameters:
  kind: Managed
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Below is how I am using the storage class to create `Dynamic PV`

```
spec:
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: test
      spec:
        accessModes: "ReadWriteOnce"
        storageClassName: "azuredisk-premium-retain"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1Gi
```